# Java readByte() blocks the application

Tags: java, timeout

the following loop seems to block the whole server application, if the client has suddenly disconnected and EOF exception is raised:

```
String a = "";
int amount = 1;
while(((cr = streamIn.readByte()) != EOF))
{
 if(amount < 100)
 {
  a+=(char)cr;
  amount++;
 }
 else
  break;
}
```

According to the function description:
readByte(): receive a byte. the method will block, until data is available.

**The question is, how can i make it timeout so it only blocks for a few seconds at most?**

Comment: How do you get the streamIn? Is a raw socket? An stream from a Servlet? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried settings [Socket.setSoTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: yes, this exits the application completely, if there is nothing going on, i only want it to stop reading from the socket if its been waiting for too long on ONE client, but still listen to the new connections, so it can start reading again

Comment: It won't exit the application completely unless you rethrow the SocketException all the way up past the entry point of your application (or if you do something bad like System.exit). Just catch the SocketException, log it, and proceed on normally.

Comment: @НоГеБаТоР, In this case, catch the exception and close the connection.

Comment: thanks, tried it, but now it drops the connection if the client is idle :( i really need to drop it only if it reads something from the client, but does it for too long

Comment: There is no way to know when the reading of actual data starts so you cannot time how long the read takes. You can time how long it take to get data after a certain point i.e. once you see X you expect Y within N seconds. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So don't close the connection when you catch the SocketTimeoutException!

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey yes thats exactly it, the answer below does what i need pretty much. @ EJP then I cant drop the client when I do catch it, so it will once again be there forever... then what is the point of having Socket.setSoTimeout() ????

Comment: So you can do something else while waiting for the client. It up to you if you wan tto do this in the same thread (if you use another thread you don't need to do this) If you don't wan tto keep the socket, you can close it. If you are not going to do anything on a timeout and you are just going to keep reading, I don't understand the point of the question.

Comment: @  Peter Lawrey ... i dont understand the point of your comment - the question was already answered. and the point of the question was: I DIDNT KNOW HOW TO MAKE THE WILE LOOP NOT BLOCK. please read everything next time before commenting.

Comment: @НоГеБаТоР, Ummm, I have 12 years experience in Java and 16,300 points and you have 1 point, but you assume that because you don't understand a comment I made, it must be because I didn't read the question.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey I did understand your comment, yes, im a noob in java and i dont have 16k points here, but here it goes: "So you can do something else while waiting for the client" -Yes, I can, but it wouldnt make sense, as I only want to do something when i have a client. "If you don't wan to keep the socket, you can close it" - NO, I cant, as the app is BLOCKED and yes, I would want to close the socket and not block it, but i didnt know how to. Essentially the problem was that the server process is getting blocked by its tread

Comment: (as it was waiting on the decision to be made by a thread *Yes, stupid of me, i know, but im a noob*). I think the question was quite clear... if you think otherwise please comment on what exactly should i have changed in it, so guru like you would understand what I need. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. In any case the question was about readByte() and somehow changed to Socket.setSoTimeout(), which had nothing to do with the problem. Commenting about it was quite pointles imo. The question was ment to say that readByte() is blocking "some" app, how do I make a loop that reads NOT block for more then X seconds. thats it. sorry for continuing here. P.P.S. I will delete all the non-relevant comments by tomorrow.

Comment: You can close a socket by just calling close().  You can do this in another thread at anytime whether you are blocking on a read or not, OR you can set a read timeout and you can, optionallty, close the connection when the blocking thread throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What server is that ? I mean it blocks the thread that serves the client that suddenly drops...it should still serve the other clients

Comment: its multithreaded, so it spawns new thread for each client, I thought as you did, but jstack of the main thread says "BLOCKING" and pointing at line with the readByte() on it... so just want to make sure that it doesnt, so i decided to add a timer task.. maybe it will  help ;) Essentially I want it to be : while(NOT_TIMED_OUT){DO THE REST HERE}

Answer (score 0):

Look into using inputStream.available() which returns the number of bytes which can be retrieved without blocking.

(Untested) Example:

```
String a = "";
int amount = 1;
int available = 0;
while(true){
    int available = streamIn.available();
    if(available <= 0){
        continue;
    }   
    byte cr = streamIn.readByte();
    if(cr == EOF){
        break;
    }
    if(amount < 100){
        a+=(char)cr;
        amount++;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ive rewitten the loop to be the following:

int i = streamIn.available();

while(i>0 && i<100)

{

 if((cr = streamIn.readByte()) != EOF)
 
 {
 
  a+=(char)cr;
  
  amount++;
  
 }
 
 else
 
  break;
  

 i--;
}
but now i get a new exception :

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException


Whats wrong with this java... im giving up ((

Comment: You want to do the available check inside the loop. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: alright! nice one, thanks ! this now works just the way i wanted it ! thank you so much!